# Restricting Laravel log viewer access to Administrators using Spatie Permissions

Tags: php, laravel, roles, laravel-permission

I'm using Spatie to manage permissions and installed a log-viewer to see logs. The problem is that everyone can see the logs in the address `/log-viewer`. I want only the administrator to have access to this panel. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict access to the log viewer by creating a new Laravel middleware that checks if the authenticated user has the 'admin' role. If they do, they can proceed to the log viewer. If not, they will be redirected, or an error will be shown.

```bash
php artisan make:middleware AdminMiddleware
```

This command will create a new middleware file in `app/Http/Middleware/AdminMiddleware.php`. Open this file and modify the `handle` method.

```php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AdminMiddleware
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        // Redirect to home page or show an error
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Next, you need to register your middleware in `app/Http/Kernel.php`.

```php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    // ...
    'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,
];
```

Finally, you can apply this middleware to your log viewer routes in `/routes/web.php`.

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::get('/log-viewer', 'LogViewerController@index');
});
```

In this code, `'middleware' => 'admin'` applies the `AdminMiddleware` to all routes defined in the group. This means that only users with the 'admin' role can access these routes.

Comment: read more about this here 
https://github.com/opcodesio/log-viewer/discussions/16